# Printing in JavaFX using lookup

Tags: printing, javafx, scene

I try to print a treetableview, and i am now landed by using lookup like bellow. The problem is although the lookup id refers to the hole of treetableview, but it prints just part of it. How can I split my treetableview in more nodes and print them over multiple pages? I have tried

```
printerJob.getJobSettings().setPageRanges(new PageRange(1,5));
```

but i did not work. In swing it happened automatically if treetable was bigger to fit on a page. I do not want to make cells smaller.

```
@FXML
private void doPrint(){
 PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
   PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
   if(printerJob.showPrintDialog(main.getPrimaryStage().getOwner()) && printerJob.printPage(main.getPrimaryStage().getScene().lookup("#treeTable")))
       printerJob.endJob();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently cannot do it.

[There is a feature request for this](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-39996). Feel free to Vote for it.

Though, if you do not want the `TreeTableView` node, you can segregate the *data* and print it using some other node.